# C# accesing non static member in a static function

Tags: c#, static, member

So I have a function:

```
List<string> names = new string();

private static void getName(string name)
{
    names.add(name);
}
```

When I attempt to compile I get a:
'object reference is required for the non-static field' notice.
What do I have to do to make this member (names) compatible with getName?

I need it to be non static or converted because I want to put the results into other non static functions and forms.

Comment: why is getName static in the first place?

Comment: Its a hypothetical simplified situation.

Comment: the method name should be `AddName(string name)`.

Answer (score 11):

You need to tell the system *which* list of names you're interested in. It's part of the state of an object, an instance of the class... but which one? Maybe you've created *several* instances of the class - maybe you've created *no* instances of the class. The static method has no visibility of that - so which instance do you want it to fetch the `names` variable value from?

To put it in another example, suppose we had a class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public double MassInGrams { get; set; }
    public double HeightInMetres { get; set; }

    public static double ComputeBodyMassIndex()
    {
        // Which person are we interested in?
    }
}

Person p1 = new Person { MassInGrams = 76203, HeightInMetres = 1.8 };
Person p2 = new Person { MassInGrams = 65000, HeightInMetres = 1.7 };

double bmi = Person.ComputeBodyMassIndex();
```

What would you expect the result to be? You've asked the `Person` class to compute "the BMI" but without telling it *whose* BMI to compute. You need to give it that information.

Some options for your situation:

- Change `names` to be static instead
- Change the method to be an instance method
- Pass in an instance of the class
- Create an instance of the class, possibly returning it
- Fetch an instance of the class some other way

By the way, that's a very strange method name for something which *adds* a name. It's also somewhat unconventional...

Comment: Can you explain the instance method solution a bit more. Using the example I created. I believe that names is currently a reference.

Comment: @Drake: `names` would be a reference to a `List<string>` instance - you need a reference to an instance of the containing class. Look at my `Person` example for an example which should demonstrate why there's a problem. Once you've understood the issue, you may have more of an idea of what to do.

Comment: @Drake - In order to `ComputeBodyMassIndex()` the system needs to know which person to compute on.  So you pass in a Person object and your `ComputeBodyMassIndex()` now takes in that person `public static double ComputeBodyMassIndex(Person p)` then one can compute the BMI.  In your case you want to add a `string` to a `List<string>`.  The issue is `names` is part of the class, when you create an object of that class you can access names directly.

Comment: Its not a function that I call so this wouldn't be applicable. Its a win32 callback function that I need to access. The callback is static, my list is not.

Comment: @Drake: It's not clear exactly what you mean when you say it's a win32 callback function. Do you mean it's something you somehow pass into a Win32 function as a delegate, and it gets called back? If so, just make it an instance method instead and construct an appropriate delegate with the right target.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `names` static if you want to use it from inside of a static method:

```
 // If this is static, you can use it from your static method
 static List<string> names = new List<string>();
```

The issue is that `getName` is defined *on your type*, not on an instance of the type.  However, `names` is defined so each *instance* of your type gets its own value.

Comment: @Drake: You can access static members from instances, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

`names` is an object that will exist in the instances of the class e.g. `MyClass mc = new MyClass();` then you can access `mc.names`. A static field can be called without an instance of the class just with the classname, e.g. `MyClass.getName("");` will work. So when you think logically, the class doesn't contain names, only 'the instances of that class' contain it. Therefore, you either make that list static too and it will be 'the same List instance' everywhere when you call `MyClass.names` or make the getName method non-static, and it will be only called from instances, therefore no `MyClass.getName("")` will be possible, but `mc.getName("");` It's a matter of what you are exactly trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can not access class fields. Either make names static, or make getName() non-static. What do you mean by "Compatible". Ask yourself... does the method need to be static? What is its purpose and how do you intend to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You cant access it this way, you need to instanciate the class containing a member.