# Regarding static behaviour

Tags: c#

from static function we can create a instance but we can not access any non-static data member....why.

```
public static DropoffType DROP_BOX
        {
            get
            {
                DropoffType tempType = new DropoffType();
                tempType.DropoffTypeSelected = _DROP_BOX;
                y=11; // compile time error
                return tempType;
            }
        }
```

from the above code we can see that instance can be created from property but when we are trying to access any non-static data member then i am getting complile time error. can any one explain the reason in detail that why instance can be created from any where but non-static data member can't be access from static function.

Comment: It's possible this should be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615909/ but I', not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `y` is an instance field, you can't access it without telling it ***which object*** you mean. For an instance member, there is an implicit `this.`, i.e. `this.y`.

Just add:

```
tempType.y = 11;
```

The problem is, you could have *any number* of variables and objects kicking around. And even for an instance method you often have to disambiguate, i.e.

```
public int CompareTo(Foo other) {
    return string.Compare(this.Bar, other.Bar);
}
```

(in the above the `this.` is not strictly needed, but helps the reader IMO; the `other.` is entirely necessary)

Answer (score 2):

You can access an instance member from a static member - so long as you specify the instance you're talking about.

Assuming `y` is an instance variable in the type of the containing class of the DROP_BOX property (nasty property name, by the way), *which* instance would you expect it to change the state of?

Just remember that instance members relate to a *specific instance* of the type, whereas static members relate to the *type itself*, and not to a specific instance.

If you could give a more complete example where you're having problems, we may be able to help more.

See [my answer to a similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615909/c-accesing-non-static-member-in-a-static-function/6615945#6615945) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Because a static function is not bound to a specific object instance.

Answer (score 1):

The static function can only access static members because you can create a arbitrary number of objects and static members do not belong to an instance but to the class.

Say you do

```
var x1 = new DropoffType();
var x2 = new DropoffType();

DropoffType.SomeStaticFunction();
```

and the static function sets `y = 11`. Which object should get the state you set? None? All? The Last one? The first one?